# How do I see which python loggers have been created by the logging module?

Tags: python, logging

How can I obtain a list or dict of `logging.Logger` objects which have been created in the current Python process by the `logging.getLogger()` method?

*Note: this already has an answer [here](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/621740/), but I thought it would be easier to find on SO. Credit to the authors at that link.*

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a dict of loggers with `logging.Logger.manager.LoggerDict`.

This is a dict of the format:

```
{
    '<name passed in logging.getLogger(name) call>': <logging.Logger instance>,
    ...
}
```